# How do I set a prefix in my ASP.NET Core 7 Web API for all endpoints?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7.0, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am retrieving a string from my `appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    //several strings
  },
  "BaseRoute": {
    "Base": "/myapi/"
  }
}
```

And I have class:

```
public class BaseRoute
{
    public string Base { get; set; }
}
```

In my `Program.cs` I have configured:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// ...
builder.Services.Configure<BaseRoute>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("BaseRoute"));
var baseroute = builder.Configuration.GetSection("BaseRoute").Get<BaseRoute>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(resolver => resolver.GetRequiredService<IOptions<BaseRoute>>().Value);
// ...
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseMiddleware<JwtRefresher>();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.UsePathBase(new PathString(baseroute.Base));
app.UseRouting();
app.Run();
```

But no prefix is set in my Swagger endpoints when I run the api.
How should I solve this?

I even tried placing the `app.UsePathBase(new PathString("/api"));` higher up:

```
var app = builder.Build();
app.UsePathBase(new PathString(baseroute.Base));
app.UseRouting();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseMiddleware<JwtRefresher>();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Or replaced the variable in the PathString argument with a fixed string:

```
var app = builder.Build();
app.UsePathBase(new PathString("/api"));
app.UseRouting();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseMiddleware<JwtRefresher>();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

But I still won't get the desired result.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configre swagger like below:

```
app.UsePathBase(new PathString("/api"));
app.UseRouting();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    var basePath = "/api";
    app.UseSwagger(c =>
    {
        c.RouteTemplate = "swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json";
        c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swaggerDoc, httpReq) =>
        {
            swaggerDoc.Servers = new List<OpenApiServer> { new OpenApiServer { Url = $"{httpReq.Scheme}://{httpReq.Host.Value}{basePath}" } };
        });
    });
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
```

Test
[image]

A workaround to change base path:
Delete `app.UsePathBase`(You could also delete `app.UseRouting` when you don't use `usepathbase`), Replace `app.MapControllers` with following

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern:"api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}"
    );
```

(Just note that {id?} is just a pattern, you could use it for any parameter other than "id");
In this way, you needn't to change swagger prefix.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for this solution. In the Swagger UI now the prefix is used.
Is this solution only to display the prefix in the Swagger UI in dev mode and was the endpoint with prefix already available in production in the endpoint with
`app.UsePathBase(new PathString("/api"));
app.UseRouting();`
Or was this solution needed to make the prefix available in the endpoints overall and also in production?

Comment: @PieterDreissen This prefix is just for swagger to send request.  It will not effect the real endpoint URL.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification.
I also noticed by testing with Postman that both endpoints (with and without prefix) work. Do you have any idea why that is and how to set it up so only the endpoints with prefix work?

Comment: @PieterDreissen @PieterDreissen I also tried find solution for it but no luck.  A workaround is use `app.MapControllerRoute` to change path instead of `app.usebasepath`. You could try the method I add to this answer.

Comment: Thanks @QiangFu for your initiative. I just posted another solution to the problem of the availibility of the endpoints with and without the prefix.

Answer (score 1):

I changed my `appsettings.json` to:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    //several strings
  },
  "BaseRoute": {
    "Base": "/myapi/",
    "BlockRoutingWithoutBase": true
  }
}
```

And the class BaseRoute:

```
public class BaseRoute
{
    public string Base { get; set; }
    public bool BlockRoutingWithoutBase { get; set; }
}
```

And then in `program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// ...
builder.Services.Configure<BaseRoute>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("BaseRoute"));
var baseroute = builder.Configuration.GetSection("BaseRoute").Get<BaseRoute>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(resolver => resolver.GetRequiredService<IOptions<BaseRoute>>().Value);
// ...
var app = builder.Build();
if (baseroute.BlockRoutingWithoutBase)
{
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/" + baseroute.Base.Split('/')[1]) || context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/swagger"))
        {
            await next();
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Not Found");
        }
    });
}
app.UsePathBase(new PathString(baseroute.Base));
app.UseRouting();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger(c =>
    {
        c.RouteTemplate = "swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json";
        c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swaggerDoc, httpReq) =>
        {
            swaggerDoc.Servers = new List<OpenApiServer> { new OpenApiServer { Url = $"{httpReq.Scheme}://{httpReq.Host.Value}{baseroute.Base}" } };
        });
    });
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseMiddleware<JwtRefresher>();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

So I used the answer of @Qiang Fu to set the Swagger endpoints and put the `app.UsePathBase()` on top.
Then both endpoints with and without prefix were available, so I added a filter before `app.UsePathBase()` is hit so only requests with intended prefix will continue in the pipeline.